# Arithmetic Progression Question (involving modulus inequalities and equations)

Tags: sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus, elementary-set-theory, inequality, arithmetic-progressions

[image: Question]

**OPTIONS:**

A) 10

B) 15

C) 25

D) None of the above

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/109918/discussion-on-question-by-sid-if-leftx2-4x3-right-4-left2x2-le).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**ABSOLUTE VALUE FUNCTION:**

$
  f(x) = |x| =
  \begin{cases}
x &\text{if } x\geq0\\
-x &\text{if } x<0
\\
  \end{cases}
$

### **SOLUTION:**

---

---

### PART I:

First let us find the rational numbers $x$ that make $a,b,c$ an arithmetic progression (AP). $a,b,c$ must be in the form $t_1,t_1+d,t_1+2d$ where $t_1$ is the first term and $d$ is the common difference.

Due to this we can conclude:

$c+a = 2b \\\because t_1 + 2d + t_1 = 2(t_1+d)$

Let $A$ be the set of all such $x$.

$$\therefore A=\left\{x \in \mathbb{Q}: |2x^2-|x|-5|+|x^2-|4x+3|| =8 \right\}$$

We can remove the **outer modulus function** by splitting A into 4 cases, with their corresponding ranges of $x$, i.e.

$
  A =
  \begin{cases}
(2x^2-|x|-5)+(x^2-|4x+3|) =8 &: (2x^2-|x|-5\geq0) \cap (x^2-|4x+3|\geq0)\\
-(2x^2-|x|-5)+(x^2-|4x+3|) =8 &: (2x^2-|x|-5<0) \cap (x^2-|4x+3|\geq0)\\
(2x^2-|x|-5)-(x^2-|4x+3|) =8 &: (2x^2-|x|-5\geq0) \cap (x^2-|4x+3|<0)\\
-(2x^2-|x|-5)-(x^2-|4x+3|) =8 &: (2x^2-|x|-5<0) \cap (x^2-|4x+3|<0)\\
  \end{cases}
$

Let us find these corresponding ranges of $x$.

**LET:** $F_1 = x:(2x^2-|x|-5\geq0) \cap (x^2-|4x+3|\geq0)\\
F_2 = x:(2x^2-|x|-5<0) \cap (x^2-|4x+3|\geq0)\\
F_3 = x:(2x^2-|x|-5\geq0) \cap (x^2-|4x+3|<0)\\
F_4 = x:(2x^2-|x|-5<0) \cap (x^2-|4x+3|<0)
$

---

$F_1:$

$
  (i)\text{ }2x^2-|x|-5 \geq0 =
  \begin{cases}
2x^2-x-5\geq0 &: x\geq0\\
2x^2+x-5\geq0 &: x<0
\\
  \end{cases}
$

**CASE $_{F_{1.1.1}}$**: $2x^2-x-5\geq0<\\(x-\frac{1+\sqrt{41}}{4})(x-\frac{1-\sqrt{41}}{4})\geq0\\\implies x\leq\frac{1-\sqrt{41}}{4}>, 
x\geq\frac{1+\sqrt{41}}{4}\\\text{but } x\geq0 \implies x\geq\frac{1+\sqrt{41}}{4}$

$\text{Claim 1 }: 1.75<\frac{1+\sqrt{41}}{4} < 2$

**CASE $_{F_{1.1.2}}$**: $2x^2+x-5\geq0\\(x+\frac{1+\sqrt{41}}{4})(x+\frac{1-\sqrt{41}}{4})\geq0\\\implies x\leq-\frac{1+\sqrt{41}}{4}>, 
x\geq\frac{\sqrt{41}-1}{4}\\\text{but } x<0 \implies x<-\frac{1+\sqrt{41}}{4}$

$\implies x\in (-\infty,-\frac{1+\sqrt{41}}{4}]\cup[\frac{1+\sqrt{41}}{4},\infty)$

$
  (ii)\text{ }x^2-|4x+3| \geq0 =
  \begin{cases}
x^2-4x-3\geq0 &: x\geq-\frac{3}{4}\\
x^2+4x+3\geq0 &: x<-\frac{3}{4}
\\
  \end{cases}
$

**CASE $_{F_{1.2.1}}$**: $x^2-4x-3\geq0\\
(x-(2+\sqrt{7})(x-(2-\sqrt{7})\geq0\\
\implies x\leq2-\sqrt{7}, 
x\geq2+\sqrt{7}\\
\text{but } x\geq-\frac{3}{4}\implies -\frac{3}{4}\leq x\leq 2-\sqrt{7}, x\geq 2+\sqrt{7}$

$\text{Claim 2 }: -\frac{3}{4} < 2-\sqrt{7}$

**CASE $_{F_{1.2.2}}$**: $x^2+4x+3\geq0<\\(x+3)(x+1)\geq0\\\implies x\leq-3>, 
x\geq-1\\\text{but } x<-\frac{3}{4} \implies x<-3, -1\leq x<-\frac{3}{4}$

$\implies x\in (-\infty,-3]\cup[-1,2-\sqrt{7}]\cup[2+\sqrt{7}, \infty)$

$F_1: (i)\cap (ii)$
(put pic)
$$\implies F_1: (-\infty,-3]\cup[2+\sqrt{7}, \infty)$$

---

**Note:** if we find the solution set for $f(x)\geq0$, then the solution set for $f(x)<0$ will just be $\mathbb{R} - (x:f(x)\geq0)$. So finding $F_2, F_3$ and $F_4$ will be easy.

---

$F_2:$

$(i) 2x^2-|x|-5 <0\equiv\mathbb{R} - (x:2x^2-|x|-5\geq 0)\implies x\in 
(-\frac{1+\sqrt{41}}{4},\frac{1+\sqrt{41}}{4})
\\(ii)x^2-|4x+3| \geq0 \implies x\in (-\infty,-3]\cup[-1,2-\sqrt{7}]\cup[2+\sqrt{7}, \infty)$
$$\implies F_2: [-1,2-\sqrt{7}]$$

---

$F_3:$

$(i) 2x^2-|x|-5 \geq0 \implies x\in (-\infty,-\frac{1+\sqrt{41}}{4}]\cup[\frac{1+\sqrt{41}}{4},\infty)
\\(ii)x^2-|4x+3| <0 \equiv\mathbb{R} - (x:x^2-|4x+3|\geq 0)
\implies x\in (-3,-1)\cup(2-\sqrt{7},2+\sqrt{7})$
$$\implies F_3: \left(-3,-\frac{1+\sqrt{41}}{4}\right]\cup\left[\frac{1+\sqrt{41}}{4}, 2+\sqrt{7}\right)$$

---

$F_4:$

$(i) 2x^2-|x|-5 <0 \implies x\in 
(-\frac{1+\sqrt{41}}{4},\frac{1+\sqrt{41}}{4})
\\(ii)x^2-|4x+3| <0 \implies x\in (-3,-1)\cup(2-\sqrt{7},2+\sqrt{7})$
$$\implies F_4: \left(-\frac{1+\sqrt{41}}{4},-1\right)\cup\left(2-\sqrt{7},\frac{1+\sqrt{41}}{4}\right)$$

---

$$
  \therefore A =
  \begin{cases}
3x^2-|x|-|4x+3| =13 &\text{if } x\in (-\infty,-3]\cup[2+\sqrt{7}, \infty)\\
x^2-|x|+|4x+3| =3 &\text{if } x\in [-1,2-\sqrt{7}]\\
x^2-|x|+|4x+3| =13 &\text{if } x\in \left(-3,-\frac{1+\sqrt{41}}{4}\right]\cup\left[\frac{1+\sqrt{41}}{4}, 2+\sqrt{7}\right)\\
3x^2-|x|-|4x+3| =-3 &\text{if } x\in \left(-\frac{1+\sqrt{41}}{4},-1\right)\cup\left(2-\sqrt{7},\frac{1+\sqrt{41}}{4}\right)\\
  \end{cases}
$$

---

**Case**$_1$: $x \in F_1 \implies x\in (-\infty,-3]\cup[2+\sqrt{7}, \infty)$

$
  3x^2-|x|-|4x+3| =13 \equiv
  \begin{cases}
3x^2-(x)-(4x+3) =13 &: x\geq0\\
3x^2+(x)-(4x+3) =13 &:  -\frac{3}{4}\leq x<0\\
3x^2+(x)+(4x+3) =13 &: x<-\frac{3}{4}\\
  \end{cases}
$

**Subcase**$_1$: $x\geq0 \\3x^2-(x)-(4x+3) =13\implies 3x^2 -5x - 16=0 \\\implies x= \frac{5 \pm \sqrt{217}}{6} \\\text{ but } x \in \mathbb{Q}\implies x= \phi$

**Subcase**$_2$: $-\frac{3}{4}\leq x<0 \\\text{but }F_1\text{ does not contain this interval i.e.} (-\frac{3}{4},0]\cap F_1 = \phi\\\implies x=\phi$

**Subcase**$_3$: $x<-\frac{3}{4} \\3x^2+(x)+(4x+3) =13\implies 3x^2 +5x - 10=0 \\\implies x= \frac{-5 \pm \sqrt{145}}{6} \\\text{ but } x \in \mathbb{Q}\implies x=\phi$

$$x=\phi$$

---

**Case**$_2$: $x \in F_2 \implies x\in x\in [-1,2-\sqrt{7}]$

$
  x^2-|x|+|4x+3| =3 \equiv
  \begin{cases}
x^2-(x)+(4x+3) =3 &: x\geq0\\
x^2+(x)+(4x+3) =3 &:  -\frac{3}{4}\leq x<0\\
x^2+(x)-(4x+3) =3 &: x<-\frac{3}{4}\\
  \end{cases}
$

**Subcase**$_1$: $x\geq0 \\\text{but }F_2\text{ does not contain this interval i.e.} [0,\infty)\cap F_2 = \phi\\\implies x=\phi$

**Subcase**$_2$: $-\frac{3}{4}\leq x<0 \\x^2+(x)+(4x+3) =3\implies x^2+5x=0 \implies x(x+5) =0 \\\implies x= 0,-5 \\\text{ but } -\frac{3}{4}\leq x<0\implies x=\phi$

**Subcase**$_3$: $x<-\frac{3}{4} \\x^2+(x)-(4x+3) =3\implies x^2 -3x - 6=0 \\\implies x= \frac{3 \pm \sqrt{29}}{2} \\\text{ but } x \in \mathbb{Q}\implies x=\phi$

$$x=\phi$$

---

**Case**$_3$: $x \in F_3 \implies x\in \left(-3,-\frac{1+\sqrt{41}}{4}\right]\cup\left[\frac{1+\sqrt{41}}{4}, 2+\sqrt{7}\right)$

$
  x^2-|x|+|4x+3| =13 \equiv
  \begin{cases}
x^2-(x)+(4x+3) =13 &: x\geq0\\
x^2+(x)+(4x+3) =13 &:  -\frac{3}{4}\leq x<0\\
x^2+(x)-(4x+3) =13 &: x<-\frac{3}{4}\\
  \end{cases}
$

**Subcase**$_1$: $x\geq 0 \\x^2-(x)+(4x+3) =13\implies x^2 +3x-10=0 \implies (x+5)(x-2)=0\\ x=-5,2 \\\text{ but } x \geq 0 \implies x=2 \\\text{but we must crosscheck if } {2} \in F_3 \text{ and indeed this is true} \\\implies x=2$

**Subcase**$_2$: $-\frac{3}{4}\leq x<0 \\\text{but }F_3\text{ does not contain this interval } \\\implies x=\phi$

**Subcase**$_3$: $x<-\frac{3}{4} \\x^2+(x)-(4x+3) =13\implies x^2 -3x - 16=0 \\\implies x= \frac{3 \pm \sqrt{73}}{2} \\\text{ since } x \in \mathbb{Q}\implies x=\phi$

$$x=2$$

---

**Case**$_4$: $x \in F_4 \implies x\in \left(-\frac{1+\sqrt{41}}{4},-1\right)\cup\left(2-\sqrt{7},\frac{1+\sqrt{41}}{4}\right)$

$
  3x^2-|x|-|4x+3| =-3 \equiv
  \begin{cases}
3x^2-(x)-(4x+3) =-3 &: x\geq0\\
3x^2+(x)-(4x+3) =-3 &:  -\frac{3}{4}\leq x<0\\
3x^2+(x)+(4x+3) =-3 &: x<-\frac{3}{4}\\
  \end{cases}
$

**Subcase**$_1$: $x\geq0 \\3x^2-(x)-(4x+3) =-3\\ 3x^2 -5x =0 \implies x(3x-5)=0\\ x=0,\frac{5}{3}\\\text{but } x \geq0 \implies x= \frac{5}{3}\\\text{but we must crosscheck if } \frac{5}{3} \in F_4 \text{ i.e. if }\frac{5}{3} \in \left(2-\sqrt{7},\frac{1+\sqrt{41}}{4}\right)\text{ and this is true}\\\implies x=\frac{5}{3}$Claim 3: $\frac{5}{3} < \frac{1+\sqrt{41}}{4}$

**Subcase**$_2$: $-\frac{3}{4}\leq x<0 \\3x^2+(x)-(4x+3) =-3 \implies 3x^2-3x =0\implies 3x(x-1)=0\\x=0,1 \\\text{but } -\frac{3}{4}\leq x<0 \implies x=0\\\text{but we must crosscheck if } {0} \in F_4 \text{ and indeed this is true} \\\implies x=0$

**Subcase**$_3$: $x<-\frac{3}{4} \\3x^2+(x)+(4x+3) =-3\implies 3x^2 +5x +6=0 \\\implies x= \frac{-5 \pm \sqrt{-47}}{6} \\\text{ but } x \in \mathbb{Q}\implies x=\phi$

$$x=\frac{5}{3},2$$

---

We have found the rational numbers $x$ satisfying $A$, i.e. $x: a,b,c$ are in AP given $x \in \mathbb{Q}$,
$$\therefore A =  \left\{0,\frac{5}{3},2\right\}$$

---

---

### PART II:

Let us now find the cardinality of the set $S$.

$S = \left\{ x\in \mathbb{Z}: \dfrac{c}{a} \leq 2\right\}$
$$S = \left\{ x\in \mathbb{Z}: \dfrac{|2x^2- |x|-5|}{|x^2-|4x+3||} \leq 2\right\}$$

Just as we did it A, we can split this into four cases:

$
  S = x\in \mathbb{Z}:
  \begin{cases}
\dfrac{+(2x^2- |x|-5)}{+(x^2-|4x+3|)} \leq 2 &: x\in F_1\\
\dfrac{-(2x^2- |x|-5)}{+(x^2-|4x+3|)} \leq 2 &: x\in F_2\\
\dfrac{+(2x^2- |x|-5)}{-(x^2-|4x+3|)} \leq 2 &: x\in F_3\\
\dfrac{-(2x^2- |x|-5)}{-(x^2-|4x+3|)} \leq 2 &: x\in F_4\\
  \end{cases}
$

If we look carefully we can combine cases 1 and 4 as they are essentially the same. Similarly cases 2 and 3 are the same. Hence, we can merge these cases.

but **note**: $x^2-|4x+3| \neq 0 \implies x \neq -3, -1, 2 \pm \sqrt{7}$ as the denominator can not be $0$.

**LET:** $G_1 = x:x\in F_1\cap F_4 - \left\{2+\sqrt{7},-3\right\}\\
G_2 = x:x\in F_2\cap F_3 - \left\{2-\sqrt{7},-1\right\}
$

$
  \implies S = x\in \mathbb{Z}:
  \begin{cases}
\dfrac{2x^2- |x|-5}{x^2-|4x+3|} \leq 2 &: x\in G_1\\
-\dfrac{2x^2- |x|-5}{x^2-|4x+3|} \leq 2 &: x\in G_2\\
  \end{cases}
$

**Note**: while solving inequalities we **can not** cross multiply.

$
  \implies S = x\in \mathbb{Z}:
  \begin{cases}
\dfrac{2|4x+3|-|x|-5}{x^2-|4x+3|} \leq 0 &: x\in G_1\\
\dfrac{4x^2-2|4x+3|-|x|-5}{x^2-|4x+3|} \geq 0 &: x\in G_2\\
  \end{cases}
$

---

**Case**$_1$: $x \in G_1$

$
  \dfrac{2|4x+3|-|x|-5}{x^2-|4x+3|} \leq 0 \equiv
  \begin{cases}
\dfrac{2(4x+3)-x-5}{x^2-4x-3} \leq 0 &: x\geq0\\
\dfrac{2(4x+3)+x-5}{x^2-4x-3} \leq 0 &:  -\frac{3}{4}\leq x<0\\
\dfrac{-2(4x+3)+x-5}{x^2+4x+3} \leq 0 &: x<-\frac{3}{4}\\
  \end{cases}
$

**Subcase**$_1$: $x\geq 0 \\\dfrac{2(4x+3)-x-5}{x^2-4x-3} \leq 0\implies \dfrac{7x+1}{(x-(2+\sqrt{7}))(x-(2-\sqrt{7}))} \leq 0\\\implies x\in (-\infty, 2-\sqrt{7})\cup \left[-\dfrac{1}{7},2+\sqrt{7}\right) \\\text{but } x\geq 0\\\implies x \in [0,2+\sqrt{7})$

**Subcase**$_2$: $-\frac{3}{4}\leq x<0 \\\dfrac{2(4x+3)+x-5}{x^2-4x-3} \leq 0\implies \dfrac{9x+1}{(x-(2+\sqrt{7}))(x-(2-\sqrt{7}))} \leq 0\\\implies x\in (-\infty, 2-\sqrt{7})\cup \left[-\dfrac{1}{9},2+\sqrt{7}\right) \\\text{but } -\frac{3}{4}\leq x<0\\\implies x \in \left[-\dfrac{3}{4},2-\sqrt{7}\right) \cup \left[-\dfrac{1}{9},0\right)$

**Subcase**$_3$: $x<-\frac{3}{4}\\\dfrac{-2(4x+3)+x-5}{x^2+4x+3} \leq 0\implies -\dfrac{7x+11}{(x+1)(x+3)} \leq 0\\\implies -3< x\leq -\frac{11}{7}, x>-1 \\\text{but } x<-\frac{3}{4}\\\implies -3< x\leq -\frac{11}{7}, -1< x< -\frac{3}{4}$

Combining subcases 1,2 and 3:

$x \in \left(-3,-\dfrac{11}{7}\right] \cup \left(-1,2-\sqrt{7}\right) \cup \left[-\dfrac{1}{9},2+\sqrt{7}\right) \\\text{but we must cross check: x must come from the region } G_1$

$$\implies x\in \left(-\dfrac{1+\sqrt{41}}{4}, -\dfrac{11}{7}\right]\cup\left[-\dfrac{1}{9},\dfrac{1+\sqrt{41}}{4}\right)$$

---

**Case**$_2$: $x \in G_2$

$
  \dfrac{4x^2-2|4x+3|-|x|-5}{x^2-|4x+3|} \geq 0 \equiv
  \begin{cases}
\dfrac{4x^2 - 2(4x+3)-x-5}{x^2-4x-3} \geq 0 &: x\geq0\\
\dfrac{4x^2-2(4x+3)+x-5}{x^2-4x-3} \geq 0 &:  -\frac{3}{4}\leq x<0\\
\dfrac{4x^2+2(4x+3)+x-5}{x^2+4x+3} \geq 0 &: x<-\frac{3}{4}\\
  \end{cases}
$

**Subcase**$_1$: $x\geq 0 \\\dfrac{4x^2 - 9x-11}{x^2-4x-3} \geq 0\implies 
\dfrac{\left(x-\dfrac{9+\sqrt{257}}{8}\right)\left(x-\dfrac{9-\sqrt{257}}{8}\right)}{(x-(2+\sqrt{7}))(x-(2-\sqrt{7}))} \geq 0\\\implies x\in \left(-\infty, \dfrac{9-\sqrt{257}}{8}\right] \cup \left(2-\sqrt{7}, \dfrac{9+\sqrt{257}}{8}\right) \cup \left(2+\sqrt{7},\infty \right) \\\text{but } x\geq 0\\\implies x \in \left[0,\dfrac{9+\sqrt{257}}{8}\right] \cup \left(2+\sqrt{7},\infty\right)$

**Subcase**$_2$: $-\frac{3}{4}\leq x<0 \\\dfrac{4x^2 - 7x-11}{x^2-4x-3} \geq 0\implies 
-\dfrac{\left(x+1\right)\left(4x-11\right)}{(x-(2+\sqrt{7}))(x-(2-\sqrt{7}))} \geq 0\\\implies x\in \left(-\infty, -1\right] \cup \left(2-\sqrt{7}, \dfrac{11}{4}\right) \cup \left(2+\sqrt{7},\infty \right) \\\text{but } -\frac{3}{4}\leq x<0\\\implies 2-\sqrt{7}< x<0$

**Subcase**$_3$: $x<-\frac{3}{4}\\\dfrac{4x^2 +9x+1}{x^2+4x+3} \geq 0\implies 
\dfrac{\left(x+\dfrac{9+\sqrt{65}}{8}\right)\left(x+\dfrac{9-\sqrt{65}}{8}\right)}{(x+1)(x+3)} \geq 0\\\implies x\in \left(-\infty, -3\right) \cup \left[-\dfrac{9+\sqrt{65}}{8}, -1\right) \cup \left[-\dfrac{9-\sqrt{65}}{8},\infty \right) \\\text{but } x<-\frac{3}{4}\\\implies x<-3,-\dfrac{9+\sqrt{65}}{8}\leq x<-1$

Combining subcases 1,2 and 3:

$x \in \left(-\infty, -3,\right) \cup \left[-\dfrac{9+\sqrt{65}}{8},-1\right) \cup \left(2-\sqrt{7},\dfrac{9+\sqrt{257}}{8}\right]\cup \left(2+\sqrt{7},\infty\right) \\\text{but we must cross check: x must come from the region } G_2$

$$\implies x\in \left[-\dfrac{9+\sqrt{65}}{8},-\dfrac{1+\sqrt{41}}{4}\right]\cup\left[-\dfrac{1+\sqrt{41}}{4},\dfrac{9+\sqrt{257}}{8}\right]$$

---

Now we must combine the cases $G_1$ and $G_2$ to get the set $S$:
$$S=\left\{x \in \mathbb{Z}: x\in \left[-\dfrac{9+\sqrt{65}}{8},-\dfrac{11}{7}\right]\cup
\left[-\dfrac{1}{9},\dfrac{9+\sqrt{257}}{8}\right]\right\}$$

We must extract the integers now. Let $pp$ be an arbitrary decimal. We know fractional part of any number lies between 0 to 1. HENCE:

$\implies S=\left\{x \in \mathbb{Z}: x\in \left[-\dfrac{9+8+\{\sqrt{65}\}}{8},-1.pp\right]\cup
\left[-0.pp,\dfrac{9+16+\{\sqrt{257}\}}{8}\right]\right\}$
$\implies S=\left\{x \in \mathbb{Z}: x\in \left[-2.pp,-1.pp\right]\cup
\left[-0.pp,3.pp\right]\right\}$

$$\implies S=\left\{-2,0,1,2,3\right\}\\\implies |S| = 5$$

---

---

### PART III:

Now that we found rational x such that $a,b,c$ are in AP and we know the cardinality of the set $S$, we are in a position to find the first $3|S|$ terms of such an AP i.e. the set $T$.

Let $d$ be the common difference. Also, let $S_{15}$ be the sum of the first $15$ terms.

For $x=0$, we have $a=3,b=4,c=5$ an increasing arithmetic progression.

- This implies $t_1=3,d=1$, so $S_{15}=\frac{15(2t_1+(15-1)d)}{2}=150$.

For $x=\frac 53$, we have $a=\frac{62}{9},b=4,c=\frac{10}{9}$ an decreasing arithmetic progression.

- This implies $t_1=\frac{62}{9},d=-\frac{26}{9}$, so $S_{15}=-200$.

For $x=2$, $a=7,b=4,c=1$ an decreasing arithmetic progression.

- This implies have $t_1=7,d=-3$, so $S_{15}=-210$.

$$\implies T=\left\{-210,-200,150\right\}$$

### The only number that divides every element in the set $T$ in the options is 10.

Answer (score 0):

The only correct option is A) $10$.

The proofs for the following two claims are written at the end of the answer.

**Claim 1** : The only rational numbers $x$ satisfying $t_2-t_1=t_3-t_2$ are $x=0,\frac 53,2$.

**Claim 2** : $|S|=5$.

Let $d$ be the common difference. Also, let $S_{15}$ be the sum of the first $15$ terms.

For $x=0$, we have $t_1=3,d=1$, so $S_{15}=\frac{15(2t_1+(15-1)d)}{2}=150$.

For $x=\frac 53$, we have $t_1=\frac{62}{9},d=-\frac{26}{9}$, so $S_{15}=-200$.

For $x=2$, we have $t_1=7,d=-3$, so $S_{15}=-210$.

Now, we want to find options such that **all** the following three claims are true :

- $150$ is divisible by $(\quad)$.
- $-200$ is divisible by $(\quad)$.
- $-210$ is divisible by $(\quad)$.

The option A) $10$ is correct since all the three claims are true.

The option B) $15$ is wrong since the claim that $-200$ is divisible by $15$ is false.

The option C) $25$ is wrong since the claim that $-210$ is divisible by $25$ is false.

The option D) None of these is wrong since the option A) is correct.

Therefore, the only correct option is A) $10$.

---

**Claim 1** : The only rational numbers $x$ satisfying $t_2-t_1=t_3-t_2$ are $x=0,\frac 53,2$.

*Proof* : $$\begin{align}t_2-t_1=t_3-t_2&\iff \left|x^2 - |4x+3|\right|+\left|2x^2 - \left||x|+5\right|\right|=8
\\\\&\iff \left|x^2 - |4x+3|\right|+\left|2x^2 - |x|-5\right|=8\end{align}$$

- If $x\le -3$, then $x^2 +4x+3+2x^2 +x-5=8$ has no solutions.
- If $-3\lt x\le \frac{-1-\sqrt{41}}{4}$, then solving $-(x^2 +4x+3)+2x^2 +x-5=8$ gives $x=\frac{3-\sqrt{73}}{2}$.
- If $\frac{-1-\sqrt{41}}{4}\lt x\le -\frac 43$, then $-(x^2 +4x+3)-(2x^2 +x-5)=8$ has no solutions.
- If $-\frac 43\lt x\le 2-\sqrt 7$, then $x^2 - 4x-3-(2x^2 +x-5)=8$ has no solutions.
- If $2-\sqrt 7\lt x\le 0$, then solving $-(x^2 - 4x-3)-(2x^2 +x-5)=8$ gives $x=0$.
- If $0\lt x\le \frac{1+\sqrt{41}}{4}$, then solving $-(x^2 - 4x-3)-(2x^2-x-5)=8$ gives $x=\frac 53$.
- If $\frac{1+\sqrt{41}}{4}\lt x\le 2+\sqrt 7$, then solving $-(x^2 -4x-3)+2x^2 - x-5=8$ gives $x=2$.
- If $2+\sqrt 7\le x$, then $x^2 - 4x-3+2x^2 - x-5=8$ has no solutions.

Hence, the only such rational numbers $x$ are $x=0,\frac 53,2$. $\quad\blacksquare$

---

**Claim 2** : $|S|=5$

*Proof* :

$$\begin{align}\frac{t_3}{t_1}\leq2&\iff t_1\not=0\quad\text{and}\quad t_3\le 2t_1
\\\\&\iff x\not=-1,-3,2\pm\sqrt 7\quad\text{and}\quad \left|2x^2 - |x|-5\right|\le 2\left|x^2 - |4x+3|\right|\end{align}$$

- If $x\lt -3$, then $2x^2 +x-5\le 2(x^2 +4x+3)$ has no solutions.
- If $2+\sqrt 7\lt x$, then $2x^2 - x-5\le 2(x^2 - 4x-3)$ has no solutions.

So, the only possible integers $x$ are $x=-2,0,1,2,3,4$.

Checking each $x$ gives that $S=\{-2,0,1,2,3\}$ and $|S|=5$. $\quad\blacksquare$

Comment: While finding S, what made u take only two cases namely x<-3. Is that the correct way to approach this in a test? What the reason to choose x<-3?... And x> that 2+root7. Solution makes sense. And follow up, why is that @mathworker21 saying the question is wrong?

Comment: @Sid : I edited your question by replacing $S := \left\{x \in \mathbb{Z}: \dfrac{t_3}{t_1}\leq2 \right\}$ with $S := \left\{y \in \mathbb{Z}: \dfrac{\left|2y^2 - \left||y|+5\right|\right|}{\left|y^2 - |4y+3|\right|}\leq2 \right\}$. I'll add some explanations about why I chose $-3$ and $2+\sqrt 7$ when I have time.

Comment: That's fine. Why did u edit the question? You told me yesterday that the AP doesn't affect S={x $\in$ Z: t3/t1<=2}... Why did it have to be changed? So I was right before? The values of the x of the AP does affect the set S?

Comment: Why can't I use the variable x while defining S, you said it wouldn't make a difference yesterday... I just don't get it.

Comment: Yesterday @mathworker21 wrote this: "I downvoted. The question is written awfully. Please rewrite it. Why are you saying x∈Q if you then just restrict to Z? I'm not exactly sure what S is. This question should have 5 downvotes." and when I asked you the **same** question (if it would make a difference) previously you said: "@Sid: No, it shouldn't. S is defined as {x∈Z:t3/t1≤2}, not as {x∈Z:t1,4,t3 are the first three terms of a decreasing AP, and t3t1≤2}." I need clarity. **Who is correct you or him?** And now you changed the question also...

Comment: This is the original question: Is there **anything at all** wrong with how it is written? If $|x^2 - |4x+3||, 4, |2x^2 - ||x|+5||$ are the first three terms of an arithmetic progression such that $x \in  \mathbb{Q}$ and $S = \left\{x \in \mathbb{Z}: \dfrac{t_3}{t_1}\leq2 \right\}$, then the sum of the first \(3|S|\) terms is divisible by:  Note $t_i$ is the $i^{th}$ term in the AP.

Comment: @Sid : I edited your question by adding another doubt so that you could get more feedback about it. If you don't like my edit, please roll it back.

Comment: It's completely fine. You still haven't answered my question. Is @mathworker21 correct or are you correct? Regaurding S.

Comment: @Sid : Reading your question and comments again, I should not have replaced $S$ using $x$ with $S$ using $y$. Apologies for confusing you by my edit. I still think that the values of $x$ in the AP do not affect the set $S$. I would think that the values of $x\in\mathbb Z$ in $S$ have meanings **only in** $S$.

Comment: $$\begin{align}\frac{t_3}{t_1}\leq2&\iff t_1\not=0\quad\text{and}\quad t_3\le 2t_1
\end{align}$$. This conclusion you can draw because t1 and t3 are greater than 0, correct? Because (x+3)/(x-3)<4 doesn't have the same result as (x+3)<4(x-3). But |x+3|/|x-3|<4 does have same result as |x+3|<4|x-3| since they are always positive. Please clarify if this is the right reason.

Comment: @Sid: Yes, it is correct.